# Unable to strip /n from html table in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the function I'm trying to implement:

```html
#Accessing webpage containing list
def save_r1000_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell_1000_Index')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, features="lxml")
    table = soup.find('table', {'class' : 'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
#look at all table rows starting with 2nd row (1st = table header)
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
#extract 2nd column
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[1].text
        tickers.append(ticker)
        
    with open("r1000.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers,f)
    print(tickers)
    return tickers
save_r1000_tickers()
```

For some reason this returns the text in the format: 'GNTX\n', 'GPC\n', 'GILD\n',

I've tried different strategies to get rid of the \n, but have not yet been successful in removing it.
It seems like it should be simple but for some reason I am unable to solve it.

For example I found a tutorial where they use a similar strategy for webscraping:

```
        for cell in tr:
            th = cell.find_all('th')
            th_data = [col.text.strip('\n') for col in th]
            td = cell.find_all('td')
            row = [i.text.replace('\n','') for i in td]
            writer.writerow(th_data+row)
```

However when I tried adding this in the following way:

```
        td = row.findAll('td')[1].text
        ticker = [i.text.replace('\n','') for i in td]
        tickers.append(ticker)
```

I get the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text' ".
I don't really understand what is going on behind the scenes here, i.e. why the ticker (which is a string, I thought) doesn't have the attribute text...
I'm a novice in python, obviously.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably because `i` is already a `str` so you can try this `ticker = [i.replace('\n','') for i in td]`

Comment: Try: `td = row.findAll('td')[1].get_text(strip=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By including `[1].text` after `row.findAll('td')` you are retrieving the text of the first item in the list that `findAll` returns. Removing it should make it work. Also, `replace('\n','')` can be replaced by `strip()`:

```
td = row.findAll('td')
ticker = [i.text.strip() for i in td]
tickers.append(ticker)
```